# Eclipse, Java, and Inspect window

Tags: eclipse

I dearly love focus-follows-mouse behavior.  Pursuant to that, I've got my Windows 7 machine set up to give focus to the window where the mouse pointer is, without raising it.  Unfortunately, this is causing problems with my Eclipse when I'm debugging a Java app.
To wit:  I'm debugging, and I select an element (such as **new Integer(3)**) and then either use the right-click context menu or hit ctrl+shift+i to Inspect the element.  The Inspect window appears, but disappears immediately.  If I can move the mouse quickly enough to put the mouse pointer in the Inspect window, then it stays around, but this has proven to be less than optimal.
I've looked everywhere I can think of for a solution.  I can imagine it would be a setting that automatically moves the pointer to the Inspect window, or setting the Inspect window to have focus when it shows up and not allowing the main Eclipse app to steal that focus back.  But I haven't been able to solve this.

Note that I've only ever noticed this with the Inspect window--the tooltip-type popups that appear when the mouse is over an element stay around long enough for me to use them effectively.

Any ideas?

Comment: as a workaround, you can always use the Variables/Display views

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? Same thing happens to me on Mac with Eclipse Oxygen. Very annoying

Comment: Nope--never did.

Comment: I just ran into this for the first time using Eclipse oxygen today.  Similar to @manoj's answer below, a Build clean fixed the problem.... but it came back immediately when I tried again to evaluate the expression that had started the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem was also faced by me today. I did:

1. refresh all project
2. select all project > right click > maven > update project > 
   force update Snapshots/Releases
3. build the project

After that my problem got resolve.

Answer (score 0):

It's a [Bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=516870), some kind of focus-issue I guess.
**Deleting the file** `.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings\org.eclipse.debug.ui.prefs` from your Workspace fixed the problem for me (this will delete some of your debug settings, so make a backup of that file).

*Other Workarounds:*

- When you hit a breakpoint, in the Debug view the focus is on the current Method you're in (see screenshot in red). If you click on the parent of that tree (the thread, in green), the Inspect-Function works fine. But as soon as you step around, the focus goes back to the current method.
  [image: Focus should be on the thread, not on the current method]
- Create a new Workspace
- context menue => Watch
- copying the expression to inspect into the
  Display-View and use Inspect from there
- hovering over a variable still works